# Ajax returning null value / asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to get multiple entiries with Ajax. However, both "id" and "qty" return null (By the way, I gave default values for them now.). Can you please help me? Please review my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
        var elem = {};
        elem.qty = "10";
        elem.id = 1;
   
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Form1/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(elem),
            
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data),
                    console.log(data),
        
                    $("#output").html(data[0]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
    public class Data
{

    public string qty { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
        public ActionResult Form1(Data elem)
    {

        List<Data> Elements = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {qty=elem.qty, id=elem.id},
            };


        return Json(Elements);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your `HTML` elements as well to that it can be reproduced easily.

Comment: My Html is like below. But I am not storing the "Id" there for now.   `@model WebApplication3.Models.Data
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="Id" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></td>
       
    </tr>
</table>

<br />
<br />
<h5 style="color:purple" id="output"></h5>`

Comment: probably declaration of your variable `var elem = {};` isn't type of `Data` class. Thats why you get null in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`"Lets focus on below code first"`***

```
        var elem = {};
        elem.qty = "10";
        elem.id = 1
```

**`Note:`** As you can see it already on `Json` fashion so you do not need to parse into json again. Therefore no need to use `JSON.stringify` in this case. So you could try below way:

**`Javascript Code:`**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
                var elem = {};
                elem.qty = "10";
                elem.id = 1;

                console.log(elem);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44361/userLog/FormPost',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: elem,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data),
                            console.log(data),

                            $("#output").html(data[0]);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**`C# Controller Code:`**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FormPost(Data elem)
        {
            List<Data> Elements = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {qty=elem.qty, id=elem.id},
            };


            return Json(Elements);

        }
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Hope it would resolved your problem as expected.