# AJAX WITH JQUERY ON C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm loading the information from a SQL database and I have a stored procedure, so I need a method to load.

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Verificar(string correoPropietario)
{
    var verificarCorreo = _PropiedadesData.Verificar(correoPropietario);

    return Json(verificarCorreo);
}
```

How can I get back from the AJAX?

This is my AJAX call:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var url =  '/Propiedades/Verificar'; 
        var correo = $('#correo')

        var data = {correoPropietario: correo}

        $.post(url,data).donde(function(data){})
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Cold you please [`have a look here in the example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672205/ajax-returning-null-value-asp-net/71672576#71672576) if that works for you?

Comment: `donde` -> `done`

Comment: You're also POSTing a complete jquery object, which makes no sense - perhaps you meant `var data = {correoPropietario: correo.val()}` (depending on what #correo actually is as you've not provided it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I get back from the AJAX, this is my AJAX

You could send request to your contrroller and then can read the response what your controller returns.

I have checked your ajax code snippet and found a issue where you have used `$.post(url,data).donde(function(data){})` which is incorrect.

In ajax nothing as `donde` which I am assuming a typos. The correct way you could refer as following:

Ajax Request Format:

HTML:

```
<strong><span id="appendHere"></span></strong></>
<hr />
<button type="button" name="submitButton" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
        onclick="GetAjaxResponse()">
    Submit Request
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function GetAjaxResponse() {
            var url = 'http://localhost:5094/YourController Name/Verificar';
            var correo = "Kiron";
            $.post(url, { correoPropietario: correo }, function (result) {
                alert("Response");
                console.log(result);
                $("#appendHere").html(result);
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Point you should remember here, you would need to [read function(result)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0) where you will get your controller response data.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check  more sample here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)